# Google Data Studio - Prevent Aggregation

Tags: mysql, looker-studio

I am trying to create a simple chart on Data Studio that pulls values from a MySQL table. The values are:

John 3

Peter 2

Mary 1

John 2

However on Data Studio, the data comes out Aggregated as:

John 5

Peter 2

Mary 1

I need to see individual lin items, but Data Studio seems to insist on aggregating them. Selecting NONE for aggregation type causes Google to declare the field as invalid.

How can I directly display line by line data from MySQL table without Data Studio trying to aggregate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this question is rather old and Data Studio has changed a lot since then.

You can also set the aggregation type to "None" in the Data Source for the second column or when the column is added to the table, edit it by clicking on the pencil icon to the left and set the aggregation there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a unique column (last name) to the data prevented aggregation from Data Studio